# Native Android VS Flex mobile filesystem speed

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, benchmarking

So i am building a couple of benchmark apps for android in order to evaluate different technologies (`Flex`, `Native`, `Html5`,etc) and determine which is best according to my method.

The problem that i came across is that while the Native app was unmatched on simple arithmetic tests it's not the same when reading or writing files.

More specific the `Native` application scored 92ms on counting from 1 to 10m while `Flex` needed an avg of 13sec for the same action.

In Reading 10000 lines of text the `Native` app took 800ms when `Flex` needed 450 and in writing the native app took 3560ms when flex took only 860ms.

The only difference on the first test was that the native app used a bufferstream when in `flex` i used a `Filestream`. Can this cause this inconsistency?  Any ideas where to go from here?

Comment: Can you post your java and as3 code? Also under native android you mean Java or C++?

Comment: I am using java for my native. so here is my source:

Answer (score 0):

I am using java for my native. so here is my source:

Flex:

```
            loadingLbl.visible=true;
            var startTime:int = getTimer();     
            te1.text=""+startTime;
            var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("samples/test.txt");
            var pathFile:String = file.nativePath;
            var stream:FileStream = new FileStream()
            stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);

            for(i=0; i<=100000; i++)
            {
                //list.dataProvider.addItem(""+i);
                stream.writeUTFBytes("word"+i+"\n");                    
            }

            stream.close();
            results.text=""+file.nativePath;
            var currentTime:int = getTimer();
            var timeRunning:int = (currentTime - startTime);


            te0.text=""+currentTime;
            timerLabel.text= "Total time: "+timeRunning+" ms";
            loadingLbl.visible=false;
```

Android Version:

{

```
    String temp="";
    TextView time = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerLbl);
    long start=System.nanoTime();

    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    //Get the text file
    File myfile = new File(sdcard,"myFile.txt");

    try {

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myfile));

        for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
        {
            temp="word"+i;
            writer.write(temp);
            writer.newLine();
        }

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // handle exception
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

    //Set the text
    tv.setText("Last word was: "+temp);
    long end=System.nanoTime();
    time.setText("Took: " + ((end - start) / 1000000+"ms"));

}
```

Can the difference of using bufferwriter be the source of getting different results?

Comment: 10x, I'll try this code. But I'll try to remove  temp variable in java code. Also measuring the time include more than writing  - findViewById and setText. The time must be measured immediately after writer.flush()

Comment: I will try that to see if i get any different results. thanx